# JSON Deserializing is not returning correct string data having double quotes at starting and ending of string

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

Following unit test is failing:

```
public void TestSerializeAndDeserializeCorrectlyHandlesQuotes()
{
   var data = "\"abc";
   var result = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(data);
   var deserializedData = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<string>(result);    
   Assert.That(deserializedData, Is.EqualTo(data));
}
```

deserializedData's value should be ["abc] but result is [ab].

when i append double quotes at both end before serialization then it works fine.

what is wrong with JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see what is the serialized result of data.

Comment: what exactly you want to do can you explain here?